# Using a macro to pass parameters to a command

Tags: macros, expansion

I am trying to pass some tags to the command `\iftagged` from the package `tagging`. See the MWE below.

From what I understand, my macro `\mytags` does not get expanded. I found a lot of similar questions here, but still cannot figure it out. Please help!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tagging}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytags}{%
tagone,
tagtwo,
tagthree
}

\usetag{tagone}

% Command
\iftagged{\mytags}{Tags passed to the command successfully!}{Tags not passed to the command!}

% Environment
\begin{taggedblock}{\mytags}
    Tags passed to the environment successfully!
\end{taggedblock}

\begin{taggedblock}{tagone,tagtwo,tagthree}
    Tags passed directly successfully!
\end{taggedblock}

\end{document}
```

The result I get:

```
Tags not passed to the command!
Tags passed directly successfully!
```

**Edit**:

`\iftagged` and `\begin{taggedblock}` are commands from the package [tagging](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tagging/tagging.pdf).

Basically, I need to have `\iftagged{\mytags}` replaced with `\iftagged{tagone,tagtwo,tagthree}` during compilation. The same with `\begin{taggedblock}{\mytags}`.

Comment: You need to specify the number of variables passed, and use their "names" #1, #2, ... See here for details: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros . It's still a macro-system, which does not use (undeclared!) variable names as we are used to from (some) programming languages.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you! Tried adding the `[num]` argument, but it did not help. And this argument seems to be optional. I just need to pass the string of tags as one variable.

Comment: Please update your code using the Edit button, perhaps you still miss a point. Unlike in other fori here is little room for discussions ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. Maybe the title confused you. I just need to have `\mytags` replaced with the string `tagone,tagtwo,tagthree`. I don't need to pass variables as #1, #2 anywhere. If I am still missing your point, can you please provide an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\iftagged` does no expansion on its first argument.

You might want to do

```
\expandafter\iftagged\expandafter{\mytags}{...}{...}
```

or take a bigger step and do the expansion right away (it should not be risky, because tags are simple strings of characters). Do the same also to `\taggedblock`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tagging}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% replace \docsvlist in \iftagged with \xdocsvlist
\patchcmd{\iftagged}{\docsvlist}{\xdocsvlist}{}{}
\patchcmd{\taggedblock}{\docsvlist}{\xdocsvlist}{}{}
% \xdocsvlist fully expands its argument before passing it to \docsvlist
\newcommand{\xdocsvlist}[1]{%
  \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytags}{%
tagone,
tagtwo,
tagthree
}

\usetag{tagone}

% Command
\iftagged{\mytags}{Tags passed to the command successfully!}{Tags not passed to the command!}

% Environment
\begin{taggedblock}{\mytags}
    Tags passed to the environment successfully!
\end{taggedblock}

\begin{taggedblock}{tagone,tagtwo,tagthree}
    Tags passed directly successfully!
\end{taggedblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\iftagged` works! Now I am not sure how to apply this approach to `\begin{taggedblock}{\mytags}` ... `\end{taggedblock}`. Is it possible?

Comment: @f-hollow Added as requested

Comment: Everything works perfectly! I will try to wrap my head around it. Thank you so much!

Comment: _For future references_: When using `\begin{taggedblock}{\mytags}` ... `\end{taggedblock}`, LaTeX throws an error 'not enough arguments for `\begin{taggedblock}` sometimes. My solution was to switch from the taggedblock environment to the command `\tagged{\mytags}{...}`.